# Safari MacOs bug on website

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have [website](http://kreatikastudio.pl/strony/zeglujapp) based on bootstrap and I found a problem with missing elements after refreshing page on Safari 10.1. Does anyone know what it is and how to fix it?

Comment: could you put some of your code?

Comment: Wait while we put on our mind reading caps. Hmmmm - no, nothing. You will have to describe the issue here... Please create a [mcve] and post any console messages

Comment: @Albeis which part of code? html, css?

Comment: The parts concernig to html,css js..Regards

Comment: @albeis This is a lot, maybe for priv?

Comment: You should be able to post the question with the main parts of code concernig your issue...try to extract them. Regards

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem. The reason was the problem of reading height of .SVG in percentages. After changing from% to px everything works fine.

Comment: Well done! Regards